# How to create controller to add new data into table for one to one relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a problem with controllers and inserting data into the database when it comes to one-to-one relationships. I have this tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `employee_detail` (
  `employee_detail_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hobby` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `work_experience` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_detail_id`,`employee_id`),
  KEY `employee_id_FK_idx` (`employee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_id_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

I have this controller to add new employees and that works fine:

```java
@PostMapping("/addNewEmployee")
public String addNewEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee theEmployee) {

    // save the customer using our service
    employeeService.addNewEmployee(theEmployee);

    return "redirect:/employee/list";
}
```

But when I want to add new employee details, it doesnt work:

```java
@PostMapping("/addNewEmployeeDetail")
public String addNewEmployeeDetail(@ModelAttribute("employeeDetail") EmployeeDetail theEmployeeDetail) {

    // save the customer using our service
    employeeService.addNewEmployeeDetail(theEmployeeDetail);

    return "redirect:/employeeDetail/listEmployeeDetail";
}
```

Its `404 not found` no logs in GF log, no data is stored into the table. What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you are calling the right path "/addNewEmployeeDetail". The status 404 means it could not find the endpoint.

Comment: Path is correct 100%. I think problem is with database and my FK, but I dont know how to fix this.  It would at least save the data to a database, so it's not a problem to the path.

Comment: If you debug your application and place a breakpoint in line: `employeeService.addNewEmployeeDetail(theEmployeeDetail);` does it stop there?

Comment: My main problem is implementing controller so I can store data to related table. I dont know how to do that.